# Windows 10 Setup has failed to validate the product key

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, windows-10

I am trying to run the upgrade from my Windows 8.1 Pro computer to Windows 10.  It keeps telling me:

> Setup has failed to validate the product key

This has happened when clicking "Upgrade" inside the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool and has also happened when running the installer from a flash drive.  However, that flash drive did successfully install Windows 10 on another computer.

How can I fix this?

This computer is a Lenovo ThinkPad T530 which originally shipped with Windows 8 (basic), was upgraded to Windows 8 Pro, and then to Windows 8.1 Pro.  When I run NirSoft's product key retrieval tool, it shows the original Windows 8 key stored by Lenovo in the BIOS as well as the Windows 8 Pro Upgrade key.  Could it be that the upgrader has "decided" that these keys are not eligible for upgrade?

Comment: @ElTurner That's what I thought too.  When I said that line about "not eligible", the key was that the upgrade checker *doesn't know what to do with OEM key + upgrade key together* - i.e. that it's just a case the current version of the tool can't handle.

Comment: Have you double-checked you're upgrading to a compatible version? In other words, since you have Windows 8.1 Pro, you should be upgrading to Windows 10 Pro and should have chosen that version in the tool.

Comment: @RegEdit Yes, I am attempting to go from Windows 8.1 Pro to Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read through the log files in `C:\$Windows.~BT` and discovered an error message that said:

> Unable to create temp file in C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp. The file already exists.

(That's not the exact wording, but it's pretty close. I'm typing this on my other machine while watching the installer run.)

I ran Disk Cleanup on the drive, which cleared out the Temp folder and the downloaded/unpacked installer files (in `C:\$Windows.~BT` and `C:\$Windows.~WS`), then started the installer again and had no trouble.

Comment: i had bad sucess with esd file from microsoft.com but the esd file in `C:\$Windows.~BT` worked

so you can try using ESD Decrypter and make a iso of that one

Comment: @wiak - You could also sip the problematic ESD files and just download the .iSO

Comment: i did it before the iso was around, worked out in the end

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain?

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers worked for me, though Moshe Katz's answer did point me to the log files. Under `C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\Panther` there are two log files, including an `setuperr.log` which indicated to me that it was in fact a license key issue. This did cause me a little confusion because I was never prompted to enter a key; I suspect Setup was attempting to autoactivate using the Windows 7 key or was looking for a Windows 10 OEM license in the BIOS.

I opened an admin command prompt, browsed to `C:\ESD\` where the media creation tool stores its files, and I ran `setup /pkey xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx` using the retail product key we purchased and Setup worked perfectly.

Comment: Your solution to run setup.exe /pkey xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx also worked for me, thank you

Comment: Thanks. Mine was looking for a 'D' drive. weird...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when upgrading from Windows 7. The solution was to temporarily remove the machine from domain.

Comment: Turns out the group policies were a bit broken, and resetting the Default domain policy fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue - below steps helped me to finish successful upgrade from Windows 8.1 to 10 worked
1. Run disk cleanup utility https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17421/windows-free-up-drive-space
2. Then (it can take a long time to execute):

> Press Windows key + X
>   Click Command Prompt (Admin)
>   Type each command at the prompt then hit enter after each scan is complete)
>   Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
>   Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
>   Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

(source  https://www.groovypost.com/howto/10-things-check-before-installing-windows-10/)
3. Additionally turned off antivirus when I started win10 upgrade